# Copy an object from R to a database file in Dropbox using RSQLite and dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, dbplyr

I am using RStudio to copy an object of dimensions 4.3M rows and 88 columns  from R to my Dropbox folder, which is synced with my laptop. I wrote the following code lines by following the first part of this code (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3026)

```
library(dplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = "./Users/[name]/Dropbox/src/[object that needs to be copied].sql")
ventra <- as.data.frame([filename])
copy_to(dest = con, ventra::ventra, "ventra", overwrite = F)
```

I got this error message: Error: The dbplyr package is required to communicate with database backends.

But after I installed `dbplyr` package using `install.packages("dbplyr"),` I tried to load `library(dbplyr)` only to get the following message

> Error in unloadNamespace(package) :    namespace ‘rlang’ is imported
>   by ‘hms’, ‘purrr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’ so cannot be unloaded
>
> Error in library("rlang", lib.loc ="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library") :
>   Package ‘rlang’ version 0.1.4 cannot be unloaded

So I tried removing `tidyerse` (ver. `1.2.1`), `dplyr` (ver. `0.7.4`), and then load `rlang` (ver. `0.1.6`) and `dbplyr` (ver. `1.2.0`), but Rstudio still gives the same error message.

**My question:** How do I correctly unload `rlang` (ver. `0.1.4`)? Also, is my code above working as I wish to (meaning, would I get a file named `ventra` in my dropbox folder after I execute the 4 code lines above?)

Comment: Try this for each package you need to remove  `detach("package:rlang", unload=TRUE)`

Comment: @sconfluentus: thank you for your suggestion. I tried that command, but same error message still appears. What did you actually mean with "for each package you need to remove"? The weird thing is, I would need to use `tidyverse` later on, as well as `dplyr`. So if I have to remove every of those packages, it means I have to run the codes above first to get the copy into my Dropbox, then re-install those packages if I want to query and do data analysis? Did you try the code above with a sample object?

Comment: Try to unload them in the reverse order that you see them, that way if there is a dependency, you remove the package using it first.  You can always restart your instance of R and try again with a clean slate and no `dplyr` loaded...

Comment: @sconfluentus: I was able to execute the code without any error messages now (although the last line should be `copy_to(dest = con, df = ventra, name = "ventra", overwrite = F)`. But I have a new question: when I check my supposed destination for the copied file in the *valid* directory path `./Users/[name]/Dropbox/src/)`, I did not see the file at all. Do you know where to find this file though?
PS: When I re-run the `copy_to` function, I got this message:
Error: Table `ventra` exists in database, and both overwrite and append are FALSE

Comment: If it is not showing up where you think is should, your path in not right. When you rerun it, it is trying to save it again (still in the wrong folder) and because overwrite FALSE it wont write it again. Try pasting the directory address in the search line of your OS to see if it takes you someplace you were not planing on or use command line to change director and look at all files, including hidden ones.

Comment: @sconfluentus: Thank you for your further help and patience. I tried everything that you said above, but I still could not find this file (I tried finding all the hidden files in Finder on Mac as well, but still nothing appears). I used a different directory, but still fails. This is the code I use:
`con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),  host = "./Users/[myname]/Dropbox/fta/src/",
                      user = "[myname]",
                      password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("1234"))
ventra <- as.data.frame(ventra)
copy_to(dest = con, df = ventra, name = "ventra", overwrite = T)`

Comment: My guess is that it is not about the code, except that somehow you are not saving the files where you think you are. Try saving to a different location and see if you can find the files.

Comment: @sconfluentus: Thank you for your help. I tried that too, but I could not find the file in the new place (I set the argument `host = ./Users/[myname]/Desktop/` this time). But then I also found out that the file was NOT saved at all. Because when I quit the current session and want to call the table I thought I already saved using `data_db <- tbl(con, "ventra")`, I received the error message: "Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: ventra" (I have to empty the workspace so that RStudio could re-load without being frozen. My saved object is *only* 4.8GB;p).

Comment: are you trying to save a data frame as a table in SQL? Or save that as a blog object?

Comment: Does the argument `host` in `con <- DBI::dbConnect(...)` function indicate the place where the file is stored when I do `copy_to(dest = con)` though? Now I am skeptical it does not do what it is supposed to do;p

Comment: @sconfluentus: I am trying to save it as a table in SQL, yes. But actually, even simpler, I want to save it as a data frame. The only purpose is that I don't have to re-run everything again, every time I open the RStudio (I cannot leave it in the workspace, as it would make RStudio frozen every time I exit or open the file again)

Comment: if you bring all your data into rStudio into your work space, then you can save your whole workspace into a single object, or you can save data frames one at a time as `save(x, "newFile.Rdata")`

Comment: @sconfluentus: but could I perform direct query next time without having to load this `newFile.Rdata`? How do we specify the directory path where the file is saved though? And also, why i cannot use `DBI::dbConnect()` in this case? Could I just do the same as this (without the "table-join" part): https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-an-r-data-frame-to-an-sql-table/?

Comment: No, and you cannot do this with a saved data frame either. You need to the  SQL database properly, write and save proper tables. you can save data frames as blobs, but it will NOT be searchable directly.

Comment: The link of the R-bloggers shows all of that component you mentioned (from SQL database to write and save proper tables), isn't it? Otherwise, do you know of a reference where I could go and learn how to do this? Spent so many hours on this;p